# Proving a Sequence of Metric Spaces does not Gromov-Hausdorff Converge?

Tags: metric-spaces, gromov-hausdorff-limit

In Proposition 7.4.12 of the book on metric spaces by Burago-Burago-Ivanov, it is mentioned that for compact metric spaces $X$ and $\{ X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $X_n$ converges Gromov-Hausdorff to $X$ if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a finite $\epsilon$-net $S$ in $X$ and an $\epsilon$-net $S_n$ in each $X_n$ such that $S_n$ converges Gromov-Hausdorff to $S$.

Is it ever possible to show explicitly that such nets do not exist for some particular $X$ and $X_n$ and so that they do not converge Gromov-Hausdorff?  What would be an example of where this can be done?

Comment: I think, this is as easy as to show that the sequence $X_n$ does not converge to $X$.

Comment: If one wishes to show that a sequence of metric spaces converges Gromov-Hausdorff, is it simpler instead that there are $\epsilon$-nets which converge?  How would such a proof typically go?